# Finding the limit as $x$ goes to $a$ of $\log(x-a)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to a} \log(x-a)=\log (0)$$

$$\log(0)=+\infty $$

Wolfram gives the answer as $-\infty$

I have added the solution's image from wolfram.

[image]

Comment: What is $\log(0)=+\infty$? is this what you think is correct?

Comment: @Rajesh K Singh : you can't believe everything Wolfram tells you, especially if the question involves infinity or fractional powers or square roots of complex numbers.  Try the simple quadratic x^2+x+1=0 (with real integer coefficients!) and watch what garbage WolframAlpha gives you for the exact solutions.

Comment: First of all writing $\log 0 = +\infty$ is plain naive. Even if we allow naivety, then it is wrong and it should be $\log 0 = -\infty$ in the same naive sense. A proper meaning of this equation is that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\log x = -\infty$ which itself means that "given any number K, there is another number $\delta > 0$ such that $\log x < K$ for all $x$ with $0 < x < \delta$". And then you need to note that $\lim_{x \to a^{+}}\log (x - a) = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\log h$ under the substitution $x = a + h$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$y=log x$$
$$\Rightarrow e^y=x$$
x will be $0$ if y is $-\infty$ and $\infty$ if y is $\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Let $h=x-a$, then as $x \to a$, $h \to 0$.

So

$$\lim_{x \to a} \log {(x-a)}=\lim_{h \to 0} \log {h}=-\infty$$

Geometrically, we can see that the $\log$ function approaches $-\infty$ as $h$ approaches $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the graph of $y=\log(x-a).$

This graph is a graph such that the graph of $y=\log x$ is parallel-shifted by $a$ in the $x$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

Graphically it tends to -infinite too (on a=1 or any other  number)

[image]